# How to filter the gridview the proper way in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, gridview

I am trying to filter my gridview where only the "Approved" item, which is retrieved from firestore, is displayed.

But instead it creates a null grid view, from which i think is coming from the argument (streamSnapshot.hasData) since the "non-approved" also has data in the firestore.

below i attach the picture of the gridview and the source code of the problem.

[image: The image of the gridview]

```
Expanded(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _productss.snapshots(),
        builder:
            (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasData) {
            return GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: kDefaultPaddin,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                ),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                      streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      final String id = documentSnapshot['id'];
                      final String url = documentSnapshot['imgUrl'];
                  if (documentSnapshot['status'] == "Approved") {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ViewProduct(productid: id, imgUrl: url,)));  
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 5,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                          documentSnapshot['imgUrl'])),
                                ),
                                // child: Image.network(
                                //     documentSnapshot['imgUrl'], fit: BoxFit.fill),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: kDefaultPaddin / 3,
                                  vertical: kDefaultPaddin / 4),
                              child: Text(
                                // products is out demo list
                                documentSnapshot['brand'] + ' ' + documentSnapshot['name'],
                                style:
                                    TextStyle(color: kTextLightColor),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: kDefaultPaddin / 3,
                                  vertical: kDefaultPaddin / 4),
                              child: Text( 'RM ' +
                                documentSnapshot['price'].toStringAsFixed(2),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return GestureDetector();
                });
          }
          return Container();
        }),
  ),
),
```

This is the initialization of the `_productss`:

```
final CollectionReference _productss = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('donation');
```

Comment: We can't see how your `_productss` is initialized, but likely you'll want to add a condition to the query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: final CollectionReference _productss = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('donation'); 
This is the _productss initialization of the _productss

Comment: Thanks. Did you already try using a query based on the link I shared?

Comment: Yes it worked, i changed it to 

final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> _productss = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('donation')
      .where('status', isEqualTo: "Approved"); 

. thank you so much

Comment: Good to hear you got it working @Ahmad!  --- Can you post your working solution and explanation of why that solved the problem below as an answer? That way others are more likely to be helped by your experience in the future.

Answer (score 0):

## Skip the data events from the stream.

##### [skipWhile method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/skipWhile.html) sample:

```
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: _productss.snapshots().skipWhile((element) => /* do filter*/),
      // ...
    );
```